# Why is return getting linebreaks added to it?

Tags: php, return-value, line-breaks

I'm calling saveVideo.php via ajax and $result always has two linebreaks at the top, I don't see where they could be coming from. It should be simply the $id variable in addVideo. I need the id to ajax in the new video once it's uploaded.

Even with trim(), the output from the saveVideo ajax call in Developer tools has 2 linebreaks in front of it.

Here's all the relevant code:

saveVideo.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../model.php';

$m = new Model;
$video = new Video;

$user = requireLogin();


$video->file = $_POST['url'];
$video->lib = 0; //sets library to be personal.
$video->title = mysql_escape_string($_POST['video-title']);
$video->desc = mysql_escape_string($_POST['video-description']);
$video->userId = $user->id;

$result = $m->addVideo($video);

echo trim($result);
?>
```

the addVideo function:

```
function addVideo($video, $lib = 1) {
        // Adds video to database and associates it with a user id

        $qstring = "mysqlquery";

        $result = mysql_query($qstring);

        $id = mysql_insert_id();

        if (!$result) {
            die("Error adding video to database.");
        }
        return $id;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the code above is enough to answer the question. It doesn't seem that any of the above is contributing to the addition of the line break (i.e. carriage return u mean?)

Comment: @Link-: Actually it's more likely to be a line break than a carriage return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for unnecessary blank lines before your opening `<?php` or after your closing `?>` tags. If there are blank lines outside of a `<?php ?>` block they will be treated as part of the page content and be sent as part of the PHP response.

This applies to `../model.php` as well. Blank lines in there will do the same thing.

---

Also, when you're debugging something like this you'll save a lot of hair pulling if you use `var_dump` rather than `echo`.

```
var_dump($result);
```

This would produce output like

```
string(2) "14"
```

which would tell you that `$result` is not the source of the mysterious line breaks.

Comment: oh nice! never knew about that function.  In this case I'm using echo to be the result of an $.ajax() call so I should leave it as-is

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp or even a str_replace to remove those line breaks.

```
str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '', $string);
```